# How to set an environment variable for just one command in csh/tcsh

Tags: csh, tcsh

In bash, I can set a temporary environment variable for just one command like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar myprogram
```

Can I do something similar in csh / tcsh? I could do

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /foo/bar; myprogram; unsetenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

, but that will lose any previous value the variable had.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In csh, you can either try `env`:

```
% env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar myprogram
```

or, a subshell:

```
% (setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /foo/bar; myprogram)
```

Comment: I got tripped up by the lack of an equal sign in the second version. Shows I need to read carefully ;)

Comment: The first one is using an external program (env) which is not tcsh, hence you'll loose your context, such as aliases. I would hence suggest rather using the second one.